# creating an offline fallback page

Tags: javascript, node.js, service-worker

Using sample from [this post](https://web.dev/offline-fallback-page/) I tried to create a custom offline fallback page.

Here is the code in /dashboard/js/script.js

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {

    if ("serviceWorker" in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register("/dashboard/service-worker.js")
            .then(function (registration) {
                console.log("Service Worker registered with scope:", 
                             registration.scope);
            }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log("Service worker registration failed:", err);
        });
    }

});
```

Here is the /dashboard/service-worker.js

```
const OFFLINE_VERSION = 1;
const CACHE_NAME = "offline";
// Customize this with a different URL if needed.
const OFFLINE_URL = "/dashboard/offline.html";

self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      // Setting {cache: 'reload'} in the new request ensures that the
      // response isn't fulfilled from the HTTP cache; i.e., it will be
      // from the network.
      await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, { cache: "reload" }));
    })()
  );
  // Force the waiting service worker to become the active service worker.
  self.skipWaiting();
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    (async () => {
      // Enable navigation preload if it's supported.
      // See https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/02/navigation-preload
      if ("navigationPreload" in self.registration) {
        await self.registration.navigationPreload.enable();
      }
    })()
  );

  // Tell the active service worker to take control of the page immediately.
  self.clients.claim();
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  // Only call event.respondWith() if this is a navigation request
  // for an HTML page.
  if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
    event.respondWith(
      (async () => {
        try {
          // First, try to use the navigation preload response if it's
          // supported.
          const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
          if (preloadResponse) {
            return preloadResponse;
          }

          // Always try the network first.
          const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
          return networkResponse;
        } catch (error) {
          // catch is only triggered if an exception is thrown, which is
          // likely due to a network error.
          // If fetch() returns a valid HTTP response with a response code in
          // the 4xx or 5xx range, the catch() will NOT be called.
          console.log("Fetch failed; returning offline page instead.", error);

          const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
          const cachedResponse = await cache.match(OFFLINE_URL);
          return cachedResponse;
        }
      })()
    );
  }

  // If our if() condition is false, then this fetch handler won't
  // intercept the request. If there are any other fetch handlers
  // registered, they will get a chance to call event.respondWith().
  // If no fetch handlers call event.respondWith(), the request
  // will be handled by the browser as if there were no service
  // worker involvement.
});
```

and here is /dashboard/offline.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <title>You are offline</title>

    <!-- Inline the page's stylesheet. -->
    <style>
      body {
        font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
        margin: 2em;
      }

      h1 {
        font-style: italic;
        color: #373fff;
      }

      p {
        margin-block: 1rem;
      }

      button {
        display: block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>You are offline</h1>

    <p>Click the button below to try reloading.</p>
    <button type="button">⤾ Reload</button>

    <!-- Inline the page's JavaScript file. -->
    <script>
      // Manual reload feature.
      document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });

      // Listen to changes in the network state, reload when online.
      // This handles the case when the device is completely offline.
      window.addEventListener('online', () => {
        window.location.reload();
      });

      // Check if the server is responding and reload the page if it is.
      // This handles the case when the device is online, but the server
      // is offline or misbehaving.
      async function checkNetworkAndReload() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch('.');
          // Verify we get a valid response from the server
          if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 500) {
            window.location.reload();
            return;
          }
        } catch {
          // Unable to connect to the server, ignore.
        }
        window.setTimeout(checkNetworkAndReload, 2500);
      }

      checkNetworkAndReload();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see this mesage in page load:

> Service Worker registered with scope:
> https://www.example.com/dashboard/

**but when I go offline nothing happens,** it should bring up the offline.html obviously.